# solr results issue: solr returing results irrespective of boosting value given

Tags: solr

I am new to solr. I was trying to get results prioritized based on boosting factor.

Here is my below query.  Inspite of giving high boost value to brandName_string, solr returns results only based on `description_text_en` when I do a text search **`oral`**.

```
((code_string:(oral*^90.0 OR oral^180.0)) 
OR (variantCode_text:(oral*^90.0 OR oral^180.0 OR oral~^45.0)) 
OR (name_text_en:(oral*^10.0 OR oral~^5.0 OR oral^2.0)) 
OR (brandName_string:(oral*^2110.0 OR oral^112110.0)) 
OR (description_text_en:(oral^60.0 OR oral*^30.0 OR oral~^15.0)) 
OR (keywords_text_en:(oral~^5.0 OR oral^20.0 OR oral*^10.0)) 
OR (categoryName_text_en_mv:(oral~^10.0 OR oral*^20.0 OR oral^40.0))) 
AND (freesample_boolean:false)
```